# How to plot a binary matrix without using additional packages?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, package

I created a binary matrix and I wanna plot 1's as black square.

How can I write it without using any package?

For example, my matrix is:

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1),nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1), nrow=3, ncol=3)

image(m, main = "My binary matrix plot", col = c("white", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty concise, works not just for square matrices,+1! Chessboard of my answer actually just needs `image(m8, col=0:1)`. BTW, we can also "re-transpose" the matrix with `image(t(m))`.

Comment: @jay.sf But we don't know how ```image``` works. Maybe, your function is faster?

Answer (score 2):

If `image` doesn't suffice, we could write a generalized function using `mapply` like this one.

```
chessplot <- function(m, col=1, border=NA) {
  stopifnot(dim(m)[1] == dim(m)[2])  ## allows only square matrices
  n <- nrow(m)
  plot(n, n, type='n', xlim=c(0, n), ylim=c(0, n))
  mapply(\(i, j, m) {
    rect(-1 + i, n - j, 0 + i, n - j + 1, col=m, border=border)
  }, seq(n), rep(seq(n), each=n), t(m)) |> invisible()
}
```

### Gives:

```
chessplot(m3)
```

[image]

```
chessplot(m4)
```

[image]

```
chessplot(m8)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
m3 <- structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
m4 <- structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L))
m8 <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(8L, 8L))
```

Comment: You made a cooler solution, than I "+1" ;)

Comment: ```plot(n, n, type='n',...``` what is a first n and the second one?

Comment: @manro `n` is used for number of rows. The `'n'` in `type='n'` creates an empty `plot`, try `plot(1:3, type='n')`. Also see `?plot.default`.

Comment: Yes, NxN + empty plot. Pure R language could be used in the encryption )) Tough to tune your view to reading when you are newbie)

Comment: Upvote but why negate twice in `stopifnot`?